# CROSS APPLY Returning more than expected number of rows

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, cross-apply

I would like to only return one row from the CROSS APPLY, however I am returning multiple OwnershipID rows, different from what I get in the eSub subquery. Can someone please point out what I'm doing wrong?

```
SELECT
o2.OwnershipID,
eSub.AssetID,
esub.EntityID,
esub.Entity

FROM tblOwnership o2

CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT TOP 1
a1.AssetID,
e1.EntityID,
e1.Entity,
o1.OwnershipID
FROM tblAssets a1
INNER JOIN tblOwnership o1 ON a1.AssetID = o1.AssetID
INNER JOIN tblEntity e1 ON o1.EntityID = e1.EntityID

WHERE 1=1
AND o1.OwnershipID = o2.OwnershipID
AND a1.AssetID = 1996323640

ORDER BY o1.OwnershipID DESC, o1.[Date] DESC
) eSub

WHERE 1=1
AND o2.AssetID = 1996323640

ORDER BY o2.OwnershipID DESC
```

[image: 2139135904 1996323640 1 NPL 2139135820 1996323640 3 BSL 2139135819 1996323640 2 High Yield 2139135818 1996323640 2 High Yield 2139135816 1996323640 3 BSL]

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what the problem is here. Your `CROSS APPLY` aliased `eSub` will only return 1 row per row returned from the table aliased `o2`. it can't return more than than due to the `TOP 1`.

Comment: @Larnu I would like to only return the top row of the image that I pasted, however I return these 5. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: I don't know what that image is, where has it some from, what is it an image of?  There's no `[date]` column, so it appears unrelated to your `CROSS APPLY`, which references the column `[date]` in the `ORDER BY`

Comment: But still, your `CROSS APPLY` will only return one per, per row returned from the table object `tblOwnership o2` If you have multiple rows returned from `tblOwnership o2` then so too will the `CROSS APPLY`; 1 for each row.

Comment: You have 5 owners of particular asset?

Comment: @Larnu. Image is the query result, not just of the sub. Why would there be multiple rows from o2 if the join is on ownershipID?

Comment: @Arvo, the OwnershipID is just a PK in a table and doesn't refere to separate owners.

Comment: Because  it appears that`o2.AssetID = 1996323640` doesn't result in a single row, @ConradAddo . But impossible to know without sample data.

Comment: I've created an SQL Fiddle with sample data. I would like to return the top 1 ownershipID for each assetID in the table. If CROSS APPLY isn't the correct way to do this or if I need to change my query can you please point me in the right direction. Thanks: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/50a86/2/0

Comment: Your current query returns top 1 asset id for each ownership id - you should reverse your logic then - applying top 1 ownership query to assets one.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to return the top 1 ownershipID for each assetID in the table.

If you want to look at all records for a given AssetID, then you should only apply a range on that column in the `where` clause of your `cross apply`. Each combination of [AssetID, EntityID, OwnershipID] appears to be unique in your data. If you add ranges on all three fields, then there will be only one matching record (itself).

Working with [your fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/50a86/2/0) I came up with [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/431306/3).

```
SELECT  o2.AssetID,
        o2.EntityID,
        o2.OwnershipID as 'o2OwnID',
        eSub.OwnershipID as 'eOwnID'
FROM tblOwnership o2
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP 1 o1.OwnershipID
  FROM tblOwnership o1 
  WHERE o1.AssetID = o2.AssetID
  /*AND o1.EntityID = o2.EntityID
    AND o1.OwnershipID = o2.OwnershipID*/
  ORDER BY o1.OwnershipID DESC
) eSub
ORDER BY o2.OwnershipID DESC
```